# How can I remove background from an (video)image using OpenCV and Java?

Tags: java, opencv, background-subtraction

I just started learning **OpneCV** and started my project in Java. As Java wrapper of **OpenCV** is released recently, there isn't much documentation available.

I am trying to separate the background and foreground from video captured through webcam. I tried using the **`BackgroundSubtractorMog`** class in java but failed to get the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
  Mat camImage = new Mat();

    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        while (true) {
            capture.read(camImage);

            BackgroundSubtractorMOG backgroundSubtractorMOG=new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
            Mat fgMask=new Mat();
            backgroundSubtractorMOG.apply(camImage, fgMask,0.1);

            Mat output=new Mat();
            camImage.copyTo(output,fgMask);

            displayImageOnScreen(output);
           }
        }
```

This code just gives a blackscreen output.

Comment: Does your problem is solved?Can you share some results?

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG backgroundSubtractorMOG=new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
```

Out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, as of now, you can't use any of the BackgroundSubtractorXXX from java

(problem with the wrappers, the code is there, but the creator function is missing)

there's  a pull request for this already, hope it will get accepted soon.